# Why ab+ mode not supporting read() in python (rb,rb+ works)?

Tags: python-3.x, binaryfiles

```
import pickle
myfile=open(r'student_data.txt','ab+') #rb or rb+ works

data={}
try:
    while True:
        data=pickle.load(myfile)
        print(data)
except EOFError:
    myfile.close()
```

I thought ab+ should retain data at the same time allow read but it doesn't seem to work, can somebody point out the error in my code...